# How to print string from function which returns pointer on that string in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

This is my program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char const* voice(void){
  return "hey!";
}

int main(){
const char* (*pointer)(void);
pointer = &voice;


printf ("%s\n", *pointer); // check down *
return 0;
}
```

- *with this i'm trying to print what is returning from pointer but it seems like not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you want to keep the function pointer stuff, so just call the function instead of dereferencing; `printf( "%s\n", pointer( ) );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call a function through a pointer in the same exact way that you call a function directly, as if that pointer was function's name:

```
printf ("%s\n", pointer());
```

Starting with the ANSI C standard, the asterisks and ampersands around function pointers are optional.

Comment: The alternative notation is `(*pointer)()`, with parentheses and an asterisk.  `*pointer()` is valid but returns the first character of the string returned by the function pointer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to call the function pointers, ie use parenthesis:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char const* voice(void){
  return "hey!";
}

int main(){
const char* (*pointer)(void);
pointer = &voice;


printf ("%s\n", pointer());
//              ^^^^^^^^^
return 0;
}
```

`*` isn't needed for function pointers. (neither is `&`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yea, I was asking myself why `pointer = voice;` is working as well.